# Clickonce deployment - how to speed up the Publish to server

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, deployment, clickonce

In my project i have 85 mb files, out of which 70 mb files are Third party control dlls which dont change often,  and remain 15 mb are my application files.

When i publish the project, it is uploading all the files (85 MB) and hence taking around two hours to publish to the server.

Is there any way that i can just publish the exe and application files and then copy the remaining dlls manually to the server

or

the dlls must be copied to client machines from a specific location?

What should i do to speed up the publish?

Comment: I don't think this is a network issue.  It's very slow even on my local connection.  Something's wrong with how clickonce is using FTP.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can not copy only the files that have not changed; they are all hashed when it creates the manifests.  If you want to do that, you will need to re-sign the manifests on the server before using them.

I would publish the files to a local directory (set publishing file location to wherever you want the files, like C:\myfolder, set installation URL to the right location for the customer), then use FTP or whatever method needed to get the files up there faster.

Also, I don't suppose you can access the remove server as a file share, is there? You could publish it that way too.

I'm assuming you are using http, and the network guys have looked to see why your upload is so slow.

Answer (score 1):

If you have full control over the server you could always choose to publish to a local directory instead and manually copy the files that you need to the server. This way you only copy the files that have changed from your local directory and copy the non-changed files from the already published directory (IE using remote desktop to do it "locally" on the server)

There is nothing special about a publish other than making the files availiable on the remote server.